# Raspberry pi zero w and Touch screen - Bootup image

Tags: boot, raspbian-jessie, pi-zero, pi-zero-w

I have RPI zero W (OS: Jessie) and 3.5'' lcd touch display. Is there a way to display custom boot image (or animation) on LCD  until RPI boots up to GUI? I tried to clean boot up text, but it doesn't look professional.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your OS you will be able to install **plymouth**.
This tool allows you to create a custom splash screen while booting your OS.

Here is a useful link on  [how to set up Plymouth](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth) from the Ubuntu Wiki.